# VSCode: different tab size between save and format

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, formatting

I have set my tabs to spaces and set the tab-width to 2 of them. When I explicitly ask vscode to reformat my code (javascript) it does exactly what I expect. When I create a new line in my code, it auto-indents to 2-spaces too.

**However, when I save (manually or automatically) the code is reformatted with 4-spaces!!!**

It doesn't do this with yaml.

I believe I'm using prettier (because it says so in the status bar) a little distance from where it says `Spaces: 2`. In my settings.json it has this: `"editor.tabSize": 2`. I've also got this pretty little thing:

```json
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

Which I think means that it's using prettier. It has the same formatter logged for yaml (and, in fact, almost everything else).

Can somebody tell me how to stop this annoying behaviour without having to lose the benefits of autosave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please see, if `.editorconfig` exists in your project.

- If this is a case, edit the file (see https://editorconfig.org/) or you may discuss it with an author, if it's a shared project. E.g.:

```
[*.js]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

- Or switch off `.editorconfig` support altogether:

```json
"prettier.useEditorConfig": false
```

2. Without using `.editorconfig`, I couldn't repeat your problem (i.e. tabSize configured = 2, reformats to 4).
   However the workaround would be:

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

or even limit to `javascript` only:

```json
"[javascript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": false }
```

That would preserve auto-saving functionality, but skip auto-format.

3. Sum up on related options:

```json
"editor.tabSize":
"editor.detectIndentation":
"editor.formatOnSave":
"prettier.tabWidth":
"prettier.useEditorConfig":
"prettier.useTabs":
```

Answer (score 3):

Just disable indentation detection like this

`"editor.detectIndentation": false.`

also use

`"editor.formatOnSave": true`

and

`"prettier.tabWidth": 2,`

Comment: That made no difference at all, sorry

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I've updated my answer please check it out

Comment: Tried that, with and without a full restart, and still it makes no difference at all. Thanks.

Comment: With the `"editor.detectIndentation": false`, it works for me.